# How can we click a link and open outlook new email window with pre-populated formatted html email body

Tags: outlook

We have a requirement where we need to fetch the rich text area field when user clicks on a link and then auto launch the outlook client with the text from rich text area field..this is working but instead of formatted text it shows html source code...has anyone come across this issue before..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the formatting you can use this:

```
String emailContent = sobject.rich_text_field__c;
emailContent = emailContent.replaceAll('<[^>]+>',' ');
```